# Is there any point in buying the shack next to Onett?

Tags: earthbound

There is a shack you can buy next to Onett which costs $7,500.

[image: dat shack]

On the inside, there's not much to do.  You can't even rest.  The only thing is a magazine in the upper-right cabinet.  It says it's Issue 3, and it has some weird story about a spy having a demon baby.

[image: dat empty shack]

So is there actually any point in buying this?  Are there actually more "issues" of the magazine to find?  Or did I just waste my hard-earned monies buying it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to visit all of the photo spots ("fuzzy pickles!"), you must buy this luxurious villa. The trigger point is about in front of the couch. Otherwise, there's no mechanical point in buying this house.

You'd do better to only bite the bullet once you're ready to start looking at your album. Nudge nudge, wink wink.

[image]

At that point, you should have cash aplenty (I had $446,901) and very little to spend it on.

Comment: Aren't you required to buy the hose to visit Magicant?

Comment: @Zibbobz No, you automatically are transported there once you reach a certain point in the story. The only point of this house is for the photo opportunity.